# How to get the current value of any variable in JRE (Like debugger mode in eclipse) without sysouts

Tags: eclipse, java

Is there any way to get current value of any variable in JRE without using outs in class files. Like the one in eclipse debugger mode which shows the current value of any variable.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to obtain the current value of a variable, but without a debugger or a logger?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds                                                 Without debugger and logger

Answer (score 1):

So you want a live display of your variable values, but without using a debugger, and without using sysout?

You could write to a log file or to some database, but that won't be as "live" as the debugger.

You could also write some more java classes which use some graphical / windows tools. They would create a new window that will hold the variable values, and change whenever you call some update function in the code (or click a button, in which case you would have to use synchronized access to the variables).

Comment: I need to track it away from my application. Say 2 java applications run on a JRE (any server), i need an another independent utility to monitor valiables(in JRE) of both the java application but not aided(logging, sysout) with those java applications.

Comment: Currently eclipse monitor JRE to get current values for debugger. I need the same utility. Is it posible to get source code of debugger atleast?

Comment: @John: I just thought you could use log4j, but that is logging... Sorry, I have no idea...